# Rotating Image in List Format, Caption Needs to be Stationary

Tags: html, css

Got an image that will be in a list with other images. I want the caption to remain fixed as the image rotates away from its original position. Once it's inside

it has to 'obey' the transition rules.

https://jsfiddle.net/k8k5kkkj/

The reason why the images are going to be in list format is because that's the only way I can use pure CCS to get the 'flip' effect. I can't get images to transition this way in other formats.

Heres the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>
ul.images {
    width:60%;
    /*background:#ccc;*/
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    /*padding:0 0 2.5% 0;*/
    margin-top:5px;
}

ul.images li {
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin:2.5% 0 0 2.5%;
    position:relative;
}

ul.images li img {
    max-width:100%;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid #eee;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.images li {
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease;
    transition:all 1s ease;
    position:relative;
}

.images li:hover {opacity:1;}

.images li:target {
    -moz-transform:scale(2) rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:scale(2) rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:scale(2) rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:scale(2) rotateY(360deg);
    transform:scale(2) rotateY(360deg);
    z-index:2;
    opacity:1;
}

.images li:nth-of-type(even):target {
    -moz-transform:scale(2) rotateX(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:scale(2) rotateX(360deg);
    -o-transform:scale(2) rotateX(360deg);
    -ms-transform:scale(2) rotateX(360deg);
    transform:scale(2) rotateX(360deg);
}

.images li:target img {
    -moz-box-shadow:5px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow:5px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.close {
    display:none;
    font:0.3em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:0.3em;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#c15252;
    padding:2px 2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:-3px;
    right:0;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.close:hover {background:#d06464;}

.images li:target .close {display:inline;}

figcaption{font-family:arial;padding-top:3px;font-size:96%;}

#wrapper{width:80%;margin:200px auto 0 auto;}

a:link {text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
a:active {text-decoration: none;}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

        <ul class="images">
            <li id="onea"><a class="close" href="#gal-six">Close</a><a href="#onea"><img src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/871_dryEE/dry-ee.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Caption etc goes here...</figcaption></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<figcaption>` should only be a child of `<figure>`.

Comment: I've included <figcaption> within <figure> but the caption still moves with the image. `<ul class="images">
            <li id="onea"><a class="close" href="#images">Close</a><a href="#onea"><figure>
   <img src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/871_dryEE/dry-ee.png"></a>
   <figcaption>Caption.</figcaption>
   </figure>
   </li>
  </ul>`

Comment: Yeah, that will not fix your rotation issue which is why I did not post it as an answer. Even if you make the caption generated content (`::before` or `::after`) it still lives in the `<li>` and will still be rotated with it. Have you tried your approach (I do not know all your requirements) with a `<dl> <dt> <dd>` combo? Semantically still valid if the caption (`<dd>`) defines the image (`<dt>`)..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll have to find a way of targettin images as they are laid down outside of the list format. All of the tutorials, YouTube vids and even books cover transitions when you hover over them, even though hovering isn't supported on touch devices!

Comment: Look at the `:target` selector with named anchors? Works on click/tapped links and moves focus as well (which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: :target's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to follow the one tutorial I've found but web design is something I'm still learning about.